# SASS: Conditional Variables

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint

I'm trying here something simple. I want to set global variables according to a main class. E.g.:

```
body.professional {
    $c1: #00B143;
    $c2: #151018;
}
.container {
    color: $c1;
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: @nils I have two global variables. I want to set global variables for each one.

Comment: `$c1` and `$c2`? They aren't globals. You have them scoped to `body.professional`.

Comment: @timolawl Yep, found it. You can do on my way or simply set `!global` at the end of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Simple.

Build all the css classes in separate file then include it.

```
body.professional {
    $c1: #00B143;
    $c2: #151018;
    @import 'base.scss';
}

body.clientes {
    $c1: #4A8FE5;
    $c2: #393C42;
    @import 'base.scss';

}
```

Comment: you can just do `@import 'base';` SCSS can figure out you mean a SCSS file.